# Error: demux engine error waiting for event

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi, hpc, entropy, mpich

When I run my code on blueshark server the #PBS -e file generated these things and I have no clue about it.

> *[proxy:0:0@node09] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (../../../../source/mpich-3.1.4/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:885): assert (!closed) failed [proxy:0:0@node09] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (../../../../source/mpich-3.1.4/src/pm/hydra/tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status [proxy:0:2@node11] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (../../../../source/mpich-3.1.4/src/pm/hydra/tools/demux/demux_[proxy:0:6@node25] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (../../../../source/mpich-3.1.4/src/pm/hydr\ a/pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:885): assert (!closed) failed [proxy:0:1@node10] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (../../../../source/mpich-3.1.4/src/pm/hydra/tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status [proxy:0:2@node11] main (../../../../source/mpich-3.1.4/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206):
>   **demux engine error waiting for event poll.c:76): callback returned error status***

In the #PBS -o file shows Segmentation fault (signal 11). But I believe its not the reason why the server terminate the job. The real reason I believe: it seems that some processors waited for too long and the job was killed automatically.

My code is about the principle of Max entropy. Since some of the moment combination would crashed, which means the lambda would be 0 and that might be the reason to cause the timeout for MPI.

Is there any way that I could adjust the time limit of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv ? So that I could avoid this problem.

Please leave a comment if you have any idea about the error. THX

Comment: The output you are seeing is cleanup messages, likely related to your job timing out and being killed by PBS. `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` do not have time limit parameters.

Comment: I solved the same issue by allocating more nodes in PBS. In your case, it is surely the seg. fault.